# Calling a REST API from an MVC Web Application

Tags: php, rest, model-view-controller

I have an MVC PHP web application that needs to call a REST API. I'm unclear on whether I should be calling the API from my controller or from the model? Looking at various resources I'm getting mixed information. I assume it should be from the Model since all I'm doing is dealing with data and passing that up to the controller correct?

Some more details to clarify. I do have full control over the REST API which I'm in the process of building and is in PHP as well. The API however will also be leveraged by an iOS and Android companion app built by my team and a few other apps running on proprietary devices.

The original plan was that the web app was not going to leverage the API and just go straight to the DB to cut out any overhead, but several debates later and I'm leaning toward using the API.

Comment: The real question is: Should I have it in my app or a separate code-base? (in my opinion)

Comment: I really think you should use 'services' (classes that handle business-logic). That service should handle calls to api-s or query the db and so on...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should call the web API from the **Controller**. The **Model** is how the data is passed from the Controller to the **View**. The **Model** should only have data and no business logic.

When you get the response from the web API, the data should be put into the **Model** and passed to the **View**.

The **Model**, the **View** and the **Controller** make up the **MVC** pattern. The Controller is responsible for putting the data in to the Model, which it passes to the View. The View takes the Model and displays the data, as it has been told to. There is no Business Logic in either the Model or the View.

Ideally, you would put your API code into a class library, that the controller uses. This allows you to separate the business logic out of the website and into a separate component.

Comment: "You should call the web API from the Controller" you most certainly should not, use a service (and then service to repo or some other class type in another layer). Model doesn't pass data to View, controller does. This is a webapp not an OS GUI

Answer (score 0):

I'd call from the model if the REST resource is a representation of the model, or if you're going to need this functionality across multiple controllers.

Call from the controller if it is not 100% specific to the model representation, or if it is only important to the controller/view you're working with.

Comment: The Model should contain data, not logic. The Web API code could be put into a class library and then reused in controllers throughout the application.

Comment: I agree. The question was so vague that I wasn't sure if s/he was referring to the _population_ of the model or not. I'm also assuming that s/he doesn't have direct access to the API, or that it is in a different language, etc. Don't put methods `populateModelById` on controllers or you'll have to repeat them all over the place. *Ideally they shouldn't be in either the model or the controller*, but that could be considered out of the scope of this question.

Comment: I added a few more details to my question. I do have control over the API. The concern with breaking it out into it's own class library is how the apps will leverage those classes.

Comment: In that case, I would go with Karl's answer. Especially the part about putting your API code into a class library that the controller uses.